# GLSL - Computing screen coordinates from world coordinates not working properly

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I just implemented the "god-ray" shader from nVidia's lovely GPU Gems 3 book: [Volumetric Light Scattering as a Post-Process](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch13.html).

Anyway, it's almost perfect, except for one flaw. Somehow the position of the light is not being moved with the rest of the scene.

Picture examples:

This looks exactly as it should.

[image]

This does not. The light should be radiating outward from the white sphere, but it looks like the position hasn't changed from the first picture.

[image]

I'm doing the transformations in the vertex shader:

```
uniform vec4 light_coords;
varying vec2 light_pos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    light_pos = vec2(gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * light_coords) * 0.5 + 0.5;
}
```

Is this correct?

The position of the light in world coordinates is (0, 0, -2) It's entirely possible that the error is somewhere else in the code, but I wanted to make sure my calculations in the vertex shader were correct before diving into the rest of it.

**EDIT:** I made some changes based on what Nicol Bolas suggested below, and it's better, but still not right.

It still looks fine when the camera is at its original position, but when I rotate the scene, it looks as though the calculated light position is now too far to the left.

[image]

Here's the GLSL code I'm using:

```
uniform vec4 light_coords;
uniform mat4 light_modelview;
varying vec2 light_pos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    light_pos = vec2(gl_ProjectionMatrix * light_modelview * light_coords) * 0.5 + 0.5;
}
```

`light_modelview` is obtained here:

```
glPushMatrix()
glTranslatef(self.position[0], self.position[1], self.position[2])
glScalef(2, 2, 2)       
self.modelview = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
glCallList(self.sphere) 
glLightfv(self.light_id, GL_POSITION, self.position)
glPopMatrix()
```

`position` is `[0, 0, -2]`. It's passed into the shader as `light_coords`

Ideally, I'd like `light_pos` to be anywhere in (0, 0) to (1, 1) if it's on the screen, and greater or less than that if it's off the screen.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong? I'm still kinda new to OpenGL, so I'm a little unsure what does what.

Answer (score 4):

If `light_coords` is in world space, then multiplying it by the `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` only makes sense if `gl_Vertex` is *also* in world space. Somehow, I doubt that it is.

In general, you don't pass light directions or whatever `light_coords` is supposed to be in world space. You pass it in view space. You transform from world space to view space on the CPU, and you put the view space coordinates in the shader.

Comment: Hmm. Is there an efficient way to do that transformation? I'm using the Python bindings of OpenGL, so I'd like to keep as much as I can in the shaders or in some OpenGL call.

Comment: @DaneLarsen: You do it once per frame. I'm sure your CPU can handle doing a single matrix multiplication once per frame, even in Python. I would tell you how to do it in a shader, but I'm afraid that you'll just do that rather than putting it on the CPU and seeing how little it affects anything. Also, it would require explicitly using a world-space matrix, which is never a good thing on the GPU.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll give it a try tomorrow. Thanks for the help!